# need help of jQuery sliders in PHP foreach issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

i have one problem in my foreach slider. it is not working with css and jquery. i used nivo-slider,Craftyslide etc but they are not working on my oven wordpress template so please help me.

here is my code

```
<div id="sliders">
<?php
     foreach ($sliders as $slide) {
        echo '<li>
    <a href="'. $slide['link']. ' ">
    <img src="' . $slide['url' ] . '" />
    </a>
<div class="flex-title">'.  $slide['title']. ' </div>
<div class="flex-caption">'. $slide['description']. ' </div> 
</li>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont know much of php, but looking at it one thing for sure your mark up is invalid because `li` has no job inside a div as a child.

Comment: You haven't even started the unordered list yet. (`<ul> </ul>`)

Comment: i used it even it not working

Answer (score 1):

With PHP you shouldn't echo out DOM elements you should just echo out the data needed into the appropriate element so it would go something like this,

**HTML / PHP**

```
<div id="sliders">
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($sliders as $slide) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide['link']; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $slide['url']; ?>" alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="flex-title"><?php echo $slide['title']; ?></div>
            <div class="flex-caption"><?php echo $slide['description']; ?></div> 
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hello @mitchell thanks for reply i used your code even it is not working any other solution please help me

Comment: @rahulkashyap do you have a link to the webpage? What is that value of `$sliders` you have it defined above right? Also you where missing an `<ul>` or `<ol>` tag in your code, the slider most likely runs off a class or id that your list tag should have.

Comment: hello @mitchell now i am using this code you can check here

http://pastebin.com/mjEtf8UC

Comment: @rahulkashyap You don't have `$sliders` defined you need to get data through either mySQL DB, JSON, XML or you can just create and array.

Comment: i have defined <?php $sliders=$smof_data['pingu_slider'];?> you can se